# How to make facebook like button shows a mobile-optimized Facebook login page?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-like

I have  a mobile website designed to be shown in a iPhone app.
There is a Facebook like button in that mobile web.
If the user click the like button without logging in, the button will show a full-facebook login page, which looks like a disaster in mobile phone! Is there a way to configure the like button so that it shows a mobile optimized login page?

[picture:ugly facebook full-login-page in mobile web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUHfu.png)

p/s: in case you are curious, I do not have access to the iPhone app source code so showing native facebook login etc is not an option for me. I can only design the webpages that lives in the UIWebview in an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Facebook *should* show a mobile optimized login screen. Please raise a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs with steps to reproduce this.